# Getting location of psychical address via virtual address

Tags: kernel, windbg, windows-kernel

I am using kernel debugger to and wanted to know the page frame in psychical ram  of virtual address.
for example I have the following `0xfffff12345678911`(just example).
I have executed the following command `!pte 0xfffff12345678911` and in the results,
I get the data of PTE VA at `0xfffff22233378911` contains "`0000000000000000`"
why i get zero ?
The addresses are just example

Comment: Please specify which debugger you're using - it's hard to answer without that.

Comment: Hi @sj95126
 windbg debugger

Answer (score 0):

find _EPROCESS of the specific binary

```
0: kd> !process 0 0 cmd.exe

PROCESS ffffb70d1ee22080
    SessionId: 15  Cid: 2b3c    Peb: c064f0d000  ParentCid: 2bc8
    DirBase: 40ad1002  ObjectTable: ffffa68b45e532c0  HandleCount:  69.
    Image: cmd.exe
```

set process context to _EPROCESS of Interest by using all **.force decodeptes** and .cache **.force decodeuser** and **reload user**

```
0: kd> .process /p /r /P ffffb70d1ee22080
Implicit process is now ffffb70d`1ee22080
Loading User Symbols
```

now look at pte for some virtual address in the specified process context
lets search for a an arbitrary string address

```
0: kd> s -a cmd l?80000 "Windows Command Processor"
00007ff6`19e5b49f  57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20-43 6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64 20  Windows Command
```

sanitary check to confirm if this address belongs to our binary in question

```
0: kd> lm a 00007ff6`19e5b49f
start             end                 module name
00007ff6`19e00000 00007ff6`19e65000   cmd        (deferred)
```

yes

lets get the pte

```
0: kd> !pte 00007ff6`19e5b49f
                                           VA 00007ff619e5b49f
PXE at FFFFFCFE7F3F97F8    PPE at FFFFFCFE7F2FFEC0    PDE at FFFFFCFE5FFD8678    PTE at FFFFFCBFFB0CF2D8
contains 0A00000012EDD867  contains 0A000000048E9867  contains 0A000001298EA867  contains 820000007F382005
pfn 12edd     ---DA--UWEV  pfn 48e9      ---DA--UWEV  pfn 1298ea    ---DA--UWEV  pfn 7f382     -------UREV
```

lets confirm with !vtop using pfn and va from !process output

```
0: kd> !vtop 40ad1000 00007ff619e5b49f
Amd64VtoP: Virt 00007ff619e5b49f, pagedir 0000000040ad1000
Amd64VtoP: PML4E 0000000040ad17f8
Amd64VtoP: PDPE 0000000012eddec0
Amd64VtoP: PDE 00000000048e9678
Amd64VtoP: PTE 00000001298ea2d8
Amd64VtoP: Mapped phys 000000007f38249f
Virtual address 7ff619e5b49f translates to physical address 7f38249f.
0: kd>
```

is that right ?

```
0: kd> !db 7f38249f l20
#7f38249f 57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20-43 6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64 20 Windows Command
#7f3824af 50 72 6f 63 65 73 73 6f-72 3c 2f 64 65 73 63 72 Processor</descr
0: kd>
```